# Variable PlotStyle

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Can I change the `PlotStyle` of a plot similar to how `ColorFunction` works?  Minimal example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (If[#2 > 0.5, Red, Black] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, instead of `Red` and `Black`, I'd like `Dashed` and `Black`.  Possible?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's perfect.  For the record, `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0.5}}, MeshShading -> {Black, Directive[Black, Dashed]}, MeshStyle -> None]` solves my problem.