# Conditional styling of contour

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

[My last question on varying plot styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166211/variable-plotstyle) was perhaps too minimal of an example (and a duplicate to boot!).  Here's a more realistic example that still gives me trouble.

I'd like to plot an isocline where one function (`dg[x1,x2]`) equals zero and style it differently depending on the sign of another function (`dg2[x1,x2]`).  For example,

```
dg[x1_, x2_] := (2 (x1 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2) x1 - 2 x1^3 - 2 x2 + 2 x1^2 x2 + 2 E^(2 (x1 - x2)^2) (x1 - x2) (-1 + x2^2)))/((-1 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2)) (-1 + x1^2));
dg2[x1_, x2_] := 2/((-1 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2)) (-1 + x1^2)^2) (-1 + 7 x1^2 - 10 x1^4 + 8 x1^6 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2) (1 - 7 x1^2 + 2 x1^4) - 8 x1 x2 + 24 x1^3 x2 - 16 x1^5 x2 + 8 x2^2 - 16 x1^2 x2^2 + 8 x1^4 x2^2 - 8 E^(2 (x1 - x2)^2) (x1 - x2) (-1 + x2) (1 + x2) (x1^3 + x2 - x1^2 x2));
```

Here's what the isocline looks like and the regions that should be styled differently:

```
iso = ContourPlot[dg[x1, x2] == 0, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1},
  Exclusions -> {x1 == x2}, PlotPoints -> 50];
cp = ContourPlot[dg2[x1, x2], {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> {White, LightRed}];
Show[cp, iso]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My approach so far is to [extract the contours](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20282/6358), then `ListLinePlot` and color them using `ColorFunction`:

```
ExtractPlotPoints[plot_Graphics] := Cases[Normal@plot, Line[x_] :> x, \[Infinity]];

isocol = ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso],
  ColorFunction -> (If[dg2[#1, #2] > 0, Red, Black] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
Show[cp, isocol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works great, but I'd like other style options besides varying the color (say, thick vs thin).  This is where I'm stuck.  I tried `MeshFunctions` but got nothing:

```
ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso], 
  MeshFunctions -> {dg2[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Red, Thin]},
  MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`dg2` is sketchy when `x1==x2` due to the denominator equalling zero, but it has a well-defined limit.

```
Limit[dg2[x1, x2], {x2 -> x1}]
(* (-2 + 4 x1^2)/(-1 + x1^2) *)
```

Defining a better `dg2` when `x1==x2` helps, but isn't quite right:

```
dg2[x1_, x1_] = (-2 + 4 x1^2)/(-1 + x1^2);
isonew = ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso], 
  MeshFunctions -> {dg2[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Red, Thin]}, 
  MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1];
Show[cp, isonew]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any thoughts?  The functions `dg` and `dg2` may differ from this example.

(The eventual application is isoclines of evolutionary dynamics as in Fig. 6a of [this paper](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/let/pdfs/Geritz-etal_1998.pdf).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cp2 = Quiet@ ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[dg[x1, x2], dg2[x1, x2] < 0] ==  0,
 ConditionalExpression[dg[x1, x2], dg2[x1, x2] > 0] ==  0}, 
{x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50,  Exclusions -> {x1 == x2}, 
ContourStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], Directive[Red, Thin]}];

Show[cp, cp2]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
dg2b[x1_, x2_] :=  If[x1 == x2, (-2 + 4 x1^2)/(-1 + x1^2), 
   2/((-1 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2)) (-1 + x1^2)^2) (-1 + 7 x1^2 - 
   10 x1^4 + 8 x1^6 + E^(4 (x1 - x2)^2) (1 - 7 x1^2 + 2 x1^4) - 
   8 x1 x2 + 24 x1^3 x2 - 16 x1^5 x2 + 8 x2^2 - 16 x1^2 x2^2 + 
   8 x1^4 x2^2 - 8 E^(2 (x1 - x2)^2) (x1 - x2) (-1 + x2) (1 + x2) (x1^3 + x2 - x1^2 x2))];

isonewb = ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso], 
   MeshFunctions -> {dg2b[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Directive[Black, Thick], Directive[Red, Thin]}, 
   MeshStyle -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1];
Show[cp, isonewb]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's elegant.  Unfortunately for me, it's significantly slower (4.33s vs 1.2s).  Of course I can spare 3.13s in this example, but sometimes `dg` and `dg2` are a lot more computationally expensive, so I'd like to save that 3.6X speedup if possible.  But maybe it's an inevitable trade-off.

Comment: Huh, when I run your edited version, I get the same as my last figure where the parts don't line up (M11.2 on MacOS10.13.3).   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ChrisK, version 9.0 Windows 10 here.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague suggested the following variation, which is both fast and accurate (avoids potential problems I had with `MeshFunctions`).  Idea: make `ContourPlot`, extract contours, make a separate `ListLinePlot` for each desired style using `Opacity[0]` in `ColorFunction` to blank out the undesired parts, then combine.

```
iso1 = ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (If[dg2[#1, #2] > 0, {Red}, {Opacity[0]}] &),
  PlotStyle -> Thin];
iso2 = ListLinePlot[ExtractPlotPoints[iso], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (If[dg2[#1, #2] < 0, {Black}, {Opacity[0]}] &),
  PlotStyle -> Thick];
Show[cp, iso1, iso2, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]